# Naming: All caps need to be converted to proper naming convention

Tags: sql, sql-server, naming

We have a legacy application which is terribly written but has a reasonable data structure (only slight modification is required). The naming convention in the database however is horrible. What we want to do is convert names like `SYSTEMNAME` to `SystemName`, `EMPLOYEEID` to `EmployeeId`.

Is there a current solution to this problem? We have thought of an approach to do the following:

- Inventarise all existing words used in the database (`System`, `Name`, `Employee`, `Id`)
- do a simple find and replace to correct the casing and apply changes using a SQL statement

Is there a current system available that approaches this problem and perhaps contains a dictionary? Not willing to spend money on a commercial application this since the existing solution is viable in our opinion (the system is not very large, ~30 tables).

Comment: @t-clausen.dk this is a SQL Server system

Comment: Have you considered what will happen when you deploy on a case sensitive collation server?

Comment: You inventarise your terms to what I like to call a dictionary. It gets tricky when a term in the dictionary is the stem of another or of a keyword.

Comment: Good question is: do you need to change Sql Modules (SP, functions) too? If yes, the only one good solution to identify entity is to use TSQL language parsing library "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser" : [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if such system exists. Your requirement is so rare so i think that 
in your case (small system) the game is not worth the candle.

When i need to move DB from SQL Server to Oracle i need to rename entities. My system was larger : it has over 300 tables and over 200 other entities.
What i did:

1. Create file to map old names to new.
2. Prepare script which analyze TSQL modules definition and change name from old to new. (Better  to use TSQL language parse library).

My script was written in Powershell and has some specific enterprise logic so i cannot put it here.

My suggestion is: to be sure you will made it OK, try generate re-creation database script and then change names.

Comment: +1 for the 'game is not worth the candle'. We have done some work to automate this. I will add to my question

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to know where to put capital letters. Sure some guessing could help. But in order to make sure, you need to check the values manually

This script will give you camel case on all fields and tables:

```
select b.table_schema + '.'+a.table_name+'.'+column_name tablecolumn, 
  upper(left(column_name, 1))+ lower(stuff(column_name, 1,1,'')) newcolumn
into #t
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
join 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES b
on a.table_name = b.table_name
and b.table_type = 'base table'

insert #t
select table_schema + '.' + table_name tablecolumn, 
  upper(left(table_name, 1))+ lower(stuff(table_name, 1,1,'')) newcolumn
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Here you can select * from #t and manipulate the values to whatever you need before running last part of this script.

```
-- here is an example how you can replace columns like 
-- SYSTEMNAME to SystemName, and EMPLOYEEID to EmployeeId in the temporary table
update #t set newcolumn = replace(replace(newcolumn, 'name', 'Name'), 'id', 'Id')


--loop cursor
Declare @tablecolumn as nvarchar(500)
Declare @newcolumn as nvarchar(500)
Declare SqlCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT tablecolumn, newcolumn FROM #t
OPEN SqlCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM SqlCursor
INTO @tablecolumn, @newcolumn
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
     -- This is the actual renaming
     EXEC sp_rename @tablecolumn, @newcolumn
     FETCH NEXT FROM SqlCursor
     INTO @tablecolumn, @newcolumn
END
CLOSE SqlCursor
DEALLOCATE SqlCursor
drop table #t
```

Answer (score 0):

**We got the solution:**

We were able to build up a list of table and column names in ascending order of length:

```
Type         Value
Column       NAME
Table        EMPLOYEE
Column       SYSTEMNAME
Column       EMPLOYEEID
Column       SYSTEMNAMEEMPLOYEEIDBLABLA
```

The algorithm then analyses each name and builds up a list of known words

```
Input          Output         Word List (ordered by length descending)
NAME           Name           Name
EMPLOYEE       Employee       Name, Employee
SYSTEMNAME     SystemName     Name, System, Employee
EMPLOYEEID     EmployeeId     Id, Name, System, Employee
.. and so forth..
```

This got us to about 95%

Some fields remained incorrect due to unrecognized words. (in this case `BLABLA` will become `Blabla` while we might prefer `BlaBla`)

Therefore we can add to the input file:

```
Type         Value
Word         BLA
Column       NAME
Table        EMPLOYEE
Column       SYSTEMNAME
```

Then it will recognize `Bla` as a word and generate correct output.